# member cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify with a type name instead

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

after looking for a lot of topics with similar problems, i'm sorry but i still don't understand what is excpected of me when visual throw me that error :"Member ClassMainController.ConnectKBOnline cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify with a type name instead".

here's my code

```
    using some_API;

    private static ClassMainController MainController;

    private static void InitMainController()
    {
        if (MainController == null)
        {
            // -- Initialize MainController
            MainController = new ClassMainController();
            MainController.ConnectKBOnline = false;    //Get knowledge base data from files
            MainController.ConnectDBOnline = false;    //Get database data from files
        }
    }
```

i got the class definition here if it helps :

```
public class ClassMainController
    {
        public Thread ModelGenerationThread;

        public ClassMainController(Form inMainForm = null);

        public static bool ConnectKBOnline { get; set; }
        public static bool ConnectDBOnline { get; set; }
        [global::GeOM_Common.GOM_Grid]
        public static string DirectoryPath { get; set; }
        public static ClassSettings Settings { get; set; }
        public static string SelectedCulture { get; set; }
        [global::GeOM_Common.GOM_Grid]
        public string ClientId { get; set; }
        public ClassPeople ConnectedUser { get; set; }
```

Comment: Please add definition of ClassMainController

Comment: If the `ConnectKBOnline` is static, you can't access it through an instance, which is what the error explains. You have to access it using the type's name, eg `ClassMainController.ConnectKbOnline`. I suspect there are other problems with the code too - controllers aren't meant to be static, much less singletons.